# JScroll не обрабатывает два nextSelector, почему?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>jQuery('form[action="/orders/finish"]').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="/images/loader.gif"></p>',
    padding: 120,
    nextSelector: 'a.to-delivery',
    'autoTrigger': false
});
</script>
<form id="w0" class="mob__basket_goods-list-rest" action="/orders/finish" method="post" onsubmit="yaCounter31428018.reachGoal(&quot;knopka_zakazat&quot;); return true;">
<div class="mob__basket_goods-rest-footer-toorder">
    <a href="/cart/mobile-delivery" data-section="restaurants" class="to-delivery">Оформить</a>
</div>

<div class="mob__basket_goods-rest-footer-continue" style="min-height: 500px;">
    <div>Очень много контента.</div>
    <a href="/dostavka-edy/restoran/cheburechnaya-na-brestskoy">Продолжить покупки</a>
</div>

<div class="mob__basket_goods-rest-footer-toorder">
    <a href="/cart/mobile-delivery" data-section="restaurants" class="to-delivery">Оформить</a>
</div>
```

Получается что JScroll привязывается только к первой ссылки, а вторадая получается не рабочей, что делать?